# Check if two inputs are filled

Tags: python

I need to check if both inputs are filled.
I've already tried a single = , Also "= True" instead of "= str()".

```py
from math import *
import time


def func():
    x = input("Player 1")
    y = input("Player 2")
    if x and y == str():
        print("Okay")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Works.")

func()
```

I expect program to print: "Okay" , waits two seconds, then "Works."

Comment: Firstly, that's not comparing both `x` and `y` to `str()`. Secondly, if it was (`x == str() and y == str()`), it would be comparing to an *empty* string, which is the opposite of what you're describing. As non-empty strings are truthy, `if x and y:` would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the strings have something in them.
str() makes an empty string,
so it will never work the way you want. Instead compare strings to a boolean using this
   from math import *
    import time

```
def func():
    x = input("Player 1")
    y = input("Player 2")
    if x and y: # if you want, you can do this: if bool(x) == True and bool(y) == 
    #True:
        print("Okay")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Works.")

func()
```